# External Interface callback not listening?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I'm trying to get javascript to talk to flash, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've gotten flash to talk to javascript, but not the other way around. It seems as thought flash isn't listening to the javascript, or I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Part of the AS3 to initially call the js:

```
ExternalInterface.call("showGal", slastSelectedNumber);
```

The js i'm trying to use is:

```
function showGal(dPicture) {
document.getElementById('fullsizegallery').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("flashGalleryContent").someFunctionName(dPicture);
}
```

Part of the AS3 of other flash file I'm trying to talk to:

```
var connection = ExternalInterface.addCallback("someFunctionName", changePicNumber);

function changePicNumber(newNumber:Number):void {
picNumber = newNumber;
if (jsonLoaded == true) {
loadImageBig(picNumber);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't see anything obvious.. did you try adding a sanity check in the flash function to exclude the possibility that it's getting called but not doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: i think the problem might be that the js function is being called before the flash loads, because the flash seems to reload every time the div becomes visible again.

Comment: That's interesting. Have you tried, say, setting `visibility:hidden` or moving it offscreen, rather than changing the display?

Comment: do i need to add a listener or something? I've changed it so I don't mess with "display" but I've moved it way off screen.

Comment: there's something wrong with this line, or there's something wrong with my flash 
document.getElementById('flashGalleryContent').someFunctionName(dPicture);

Comment: It breaks in the javascript. Whenever I try to call the function, the js stops.. I don't know if that means the js is broken or if the flash is.

Comment: If the JS stpos, it's probably that getElementById is returning null, then you're referencing a property of null, which tends to make JS stop executing. Dunno why it would return null, but that's where I'd look for problems.

Comment: Could you show us your HTML wrapper around the swf? It might be a problem with `allowScriptAccess` or `allowNetworking` properties.

Comment: I ended up using local connection. I think the problem is that things are executing too fast and braking it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have something like: `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />` in the Flash html embedding.